# Unable to access 15 GB partition?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, bad-sectors, partition-recovery, sectors

I have 250 GB HDD. I have created 5 partitions of it. Unfortunately, I am unable to format, delete, access my 5th partition which is of 15 GB. It says that it is Unallocated. If it is unallocated then why It is not "format-able", "delete-able" and inaccessible. I am using Linux Ubuntu. Also, I checked it in Windows 7 and Windows 8, but it was inaccessible at all. If there are bad sectors in that partition then how can I fix them without losing any data from other partitions so that partition can be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible that you are trying to create 5 primary partitions. On an MBR disk only 4 such partitions are allowed. You may need to repartition the disk or delete a partition and then create an extended partition.

Comment: So, what is MBR disk?

Comment: "A master boot record (MBR) is a special type of boot sector at the very beginning of partitioned computer mass storage devices like fixed disks or removable drives intended for use with IBM PC-compatible systems and beyond. The concept of MBRs was publicly introduced in 1983 with PC DOS 2.0." -from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record